# MySQL Repository Key Expired

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, debian, repository

The MySQL repository key has suddenly expired again, so I get a GPG error in Ubuntu when running `apt-get update`

The error is `W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1550412832  KEYEXPIRED 1550412832  KEYEXPIRED 1550412832`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TLDR;**
The one-liner that fixes this is the following:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net 5072E1F5
```

Which basically fetches the new key and installs it into the keyring.

**A bit more detail:**

You can find the expired key by executing the following command:

`LANG=C apt-key list | grep expired`

Which outputs something like this: `pub   1024D/5072E1F5 2003-02-03 [expired: 2019-02-17]`
**5072E1F5** is the key ID, which we used in the command above.

Another one-liner that's recommended in the bug report below is this one:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu 5072E1F5
```

But I couldn't get it to work.

More reading from when this happened the last time.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85029

Comment: The `apt-key` manual explicitly warns that it is easy to break the security of apt by carelessly downloading keys. Identifying keys using **just 32 bits of hash** usually does qualify as careless.

Comment: What would you recommend then?

Comment: I [believe using `--refresh-keys` instead of `--recv-keys`](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/206405/88348) is sufficient, since the key is already known. If you wanted to download a new key, you would best specify a full fingerprint (typically SHA1).

Comment: Recent versions of MySQL use a different key. One should then use `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 3A79BD29`

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been raised to MySQL already [Bug#94378](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94378).

> Workaround which helped me on Ubuntu 16.04, installed latest Ubuntu / Debian (Architecture Independent), DEB Package mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb

You can try this workaround.

Comment: True, from the linked issue : `sudo apt install mysql-apt-config` solved the problem